# Sync framework provisioning error on table 'aspnet_personalizationperuser'

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

i have a database on server A which also contains the default tables and sp that used by the aspnet_Regsql.exe process (mainly i use the authentication module of asp.net with those tables) and a backup Server B, which i use sync framework sqlOrchester and SqlProvider to sync between them together.
but for some reason, when i'm trying to do the provisioning process on the remote server A
i get an error on the line that creates the SqlSyncScopeProvisioning object with exception of DbSyncException exception, stating that i'm missing a primary key column on table aspnet_personalizationperuser, although that table has the primary key column [Id] which ig a uniqueidentifier column.

I added the lines of code i'm using for the provisioning process:

> var TableNames = [Collection of all the table names in the database];
>
> var dbScopeDescription =
>   BuildScopeFromTableList(this.RemoteProvider, TableNames);
>
> protected DbSyncScopeDescription
>   BuildScopeFromTableList(RelationalSyncProvider provider, string[] SyncTablesNames)
>
> {
>
> DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new
>   DbSyncScopeDescription(SyncSettings.ScopeName);
>               SqlConnection serverConn =
>   (SqlConnection)provider.Connection;
>
> ```
>         foreach (String table in SyncTablesNames)
>         {
>             DbSyncTableDescription tableDesc =
>              SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(table, serverConn);
>             scopeDesc.Tables.Add(tableDesc);
>
>         }
>         return scopeDesc;
>
>     }
> ```
>
> var serverConfig = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning((SqlConnection)this.remoteProvider.Connection, dbScopeDescription);

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same problem, and I would love to see a solution to it.